# Can not connect to Google Game services

Tags: android

I wrote a program for Android. In the Google Play console, I have enabled Google Play services. In the program I want to connect to them. In the Google Play Developer console I have added my accounts to the test. Services GooglePlay are published. Unfortunately, I can't connect to Google Play service. I always get the message "No connection". Is there something wrong in my program, or I set something wrong in the Google Play console?
I append fragment of "manifest.xml", activity text and a screenshots of Google console.

Please help me! I did everything according to the description on Google Play, but from two weeks I can not find a solution.

Regards, gravedg

Fragment of file "**Manifest.xml**":

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" (my app ID is here)  android:value="@string/app_id" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Fragment of file "**Test1Activity.java**":

```
package pl.(... here is my package name ...);

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

topublic class Test1Activity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .addApi(Games.API)
            .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection Suspended", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

[Google Developer Console - services enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1gsx.jpg)

[Google Play Developer Console - services published](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrTjz.jpg)